# Make column compatible with Full-Text indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I try to create a Full-Text index on my table and it says I first need column that are full-text indexable.  What does that mean?

All my columns are either varchar or nvarchar (allow null).

This is the Tutorial that I followed:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Comment: Is your column `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)` by any chance ???

Comment: Nope, all have integer length < 100

Comment: can you add the code to your question that you used to create FTS ??

Comment: I am actually just using Microsoft SQL Server Manager interface, here is a tutorial that I followed: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Comment: check your services and make sure you have FTS services installed on and it is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant tell what and where you are doing wrong.

1st of all go to your Services and see if you have Full-Text Services installed there and if it is installed make sure it is `Running`.

Once you have confirmed it, it is there and running you can do the following steps to create a FTS Index on a table

```
/*A Table with A Primary key Defined on a column*/

CREATE TABLE Test_FTS 
(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
,Column1 NVARCHAR(100)
,Column2 VARCHAR(100))
GO

/*
Your Table have to have a PRIMARY KEY  or atleast a Unique Index defined on any 
column in your table.

Basicaly this Unique Index/Primary Key value will be stored in your FTS
working as a POINTER to the data in your table. 
*/

 /* Only create a Unique Index if you do not have a Primary Key in your table*/
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_SomeUniqueIdex ON dbo.Test_FTS(ID);
GO

/*Create a Catalog*/
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FTS_Test_Catalog AS DEFAULT;
GO

/* Finally the FTS Index */
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Test_FTS (Column1) 
   KEY INDEX UIX_SomeUniqueIdex;
GO
```